# Tips on writing a duplicate file finder in F#

Tags: algorithm, f#, hashmap

I am new to programming and F# is my first .NET language as well as my first functional language. As a beginner's project, I would like to try implementing my own duplicate file finder, and I am looking for some tips on the F# tools that are relevant to my project. I apologise in advance if my question doesn't meet StackOverflow's standards: I will gladly make changes to it as required.

Here is the rough idea I have come up with: I will retrieve all files from a desired folder, read the file contents into byte arrays, and then use a hash-table to store the byte arrays and remove duplicates. Will more experienced programmers tell me whether this is a good approach? What improvements can I make? Additionally, as asked earlier, what are the relevant F# tools to look at? MSDN has a huge list of libraries and namespaces and etc., and it is really overwhelming for a newbie like me.

Thank you warmly in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with a console application.

There are a couple of relevant .Net APIs:

- [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

`GetFiles` returns an easy to use array of all file paths but blocks until all files are found, where as `EnumerateFiles` lets you enumerate the files one-by-one and give feedback to the user.

For performance when finding duplicates, the file length can be used to find potential duplicates before comparing the data. Here you could use the [Length property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of [System.IO.FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileInfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you create a sequence of tuple of file name and file length, you could use [Seq.groupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx) to group potential matches. Finally for groups of 2 or more you can read the files and compare the bytes to find exact duplicates.

Comment: Dear Philip, thanks for your very helpful suggestions. I am having some trouble with identifying groups of 2 or more. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

`let groupByFileLengths (directory: string) =
    directory
    |> getFileLengths
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun (eachFile, eachFileLength) -> eachFileLength)`

Do I use Seq.filter hereafter to filter out the groups that have 2 or more members?

Comment: Yes Seq.filter should work well for filtering groups of two or more, you can use Seq.length against the list of files for the group (the second value).